# Borrar datos de varias tablas hasta una fecha mysql

Tags: mysql

estoy intentando datos de varias tablas de un mismo esquema que no tienen relaccion desde una fecha indicada pero estoy super verde en `mysql`... lo estoy intentando asi:

```
delete from tabla1,tabla2 where  date < '2018/01/01';
```

pero me da error de sintaxis

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de campo es date y que formato tiene?

Comment: si date es de tipo date, estas comparando dos cosas distintas. Uno es un string y el otro una fecha. Lleva todo a un mismo formato y luego compara.

Comment: Me parece algo extraño que quieras borrar datos así. ¿Lo más seguro no sería ejecutar las sentencias aparte? `delete from tabla1 where  date < '2018/01/01';`  y `delete from tabla2 where  date < '2018/01/01';`  O unes las dos tablas: `DELETE tabla1, tabla2 FROM tabla1, tabla2 WHERE tabla1.date=tabla2.date AND tabla1.date  < '2018/01/01'`.

Comment: El campo date es de formato datetime, claro esta todas las tablas tienen este campo y deberia poder borrar multiples tablas a la vez, en el ejemplo solo he puesto dos pero podrian ser muchas mas. Habia pensado como dice A.cedano hacerlo con un script una a una pero era por aprender un poco mas.

Answer (score 3):

Si la columna `date`, se contiene en ambas tablas con el mismo nombre, no sabrá a cual hacerle caso, por eso; probablemente te marque error, intenta:

```
delete from tabla1 
where  tabla1.date<'2018/01/01'

delete from tabla2 
where  tabla2.date<'2018/01/01'
```